# onedrive/ skydrive api - get file thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a file picker using the skydrive/onedrive api

I get a list of files using the url:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/'+folder_path+'/files?access_token='+onedrive_access_token
```

But this doesn't return a thumbnail for the files (unlike other api's, googledrive for example).

I would like to get a thumbnail for each file, if it exists.

I cant find anywhere in the docs how to do this - is there a way I can?

Answer (score 0):

After complete the call, you should get some result like this.

```
{
"data": [
    {
      "id": "[file id]",
      "from": {
        "name": "...",
        "id": "..."
      },
      "name": "[file name]",
      "description": "",
      "parent_id": "[parent folder id]",
      "size": 12345,
      "comments_count": 0,
      "comments_enabled": false,
      "tags_count": 0,
      "tags_enabled": true,
      "is_embeddable": true,
      "picture": "[thumbnail url] <<< this is what you want", 
      "source": "[public preview url]",
      "upload_location": "...",
      "link": "...",
      "height": 270,
      "width": 480,
      "duration": 22443,
      "bitrate": 802928,
      "type": "video",
      "shared_with": {
        "access": "Just me"
      },
      "created_time": "2013-01-01T07:27:17+0000",
      "updated_time": "2013-01-01T07:40:44+0000",
      "client_updated_time": "2013-01-20T16:26:54+0000"
    },
  ]
}
```

Which "picture" is the thumbnail url that you want.